# Vertical align of label next to a multiselect

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to know, how to place a label next to the multiselect or textarea at the top ? For example I have this code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="SelectId">label</label>
    <select name="SelectId" id="SelectId" style="min-width: 604px;" size="5" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="0">No Selection</option>
          ...
    </select>
</div>
```

which looks like at the picture
[image]

Only solution I found is with relative positioning, which works but broke when browser window is resized.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="SelectId">label</label>
    <select name="SelectId" id="SelectId" style="position: relative; top: -75px;" size="5" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="0">No Selection</option>
          ...
    </select>
</div>
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried setting vertical align for the label ? `.control-label { vertical-align: top;  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `vertical-align` you are able to position `inline` elements based on the other `inline` elements in the same line.

```
.control-label { 
    vertical-align: top; 
}
```

`label` and `select` are both `display: inline` by defaut.